# Apache Basic Authentication Back Page

Tags: html, apache

In login to my web page (it contains only from one index.html file) there is a Basic Authentication, which controlled from Apache. I want to show a background image on this step, could you please advise how to do it?
Below attached screenshot from Authentication page, where I want to show some background image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible with BasicAuth to send HTML content to be displayed before the authentication dialog, which will always use the native browser interface. The response content will only be be displayed if authentication has failed.

Comment: Hello, thank you for information. How to do it in case of failure?

Comment: maybe this documentation helps: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html